# Changing views in GridView via ViewHolder possible?

Tags: gridview

i already read a lot about GridViews and ViewHolders but nothing could help me. Dont know if its even possible or if I just cant manage it.
Problem: The GridView represents a Sudokufield which can contains either a TextView if the user enters a number or another GridView for showing the pencilmarks of possible numbers.
Idea: A ViewHolder which holds a GridView and a TextView. If the text of the TextView is empty then the pencilmarks should be shown (in a GridView) else the TextView with the number should be seen.
Heres my code for the adapter:
(Maybe there are some problems with the layout? its totally not intuitive -.-)

edit: cells is an array of Views which defines the start views in each field. so if in field x is already a number y then the cells[x] contains a textview with text set y. (i guess its a bit ugly but im not familiar with gridviews and have a lot of problems:( )

```
public class ViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
Context context;
View[] cells;
int size;

public ViewAdapter(Context context, View[] cells, int size) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cells = cells;
    this.size = size;
}

public int getCount() {
    return 81;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View target, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (target == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        target = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_game, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (cells[position] instanceof GridView) {
            holder.gv = (GridView)cells[position];
            holder.tv = new TextView(context);
            holder.tv.setText("");
        } else if (cells[position] instanceof TextView){
            holder.gv = new GridView(context);
            holder.gv.setNumColumns(3);
            holder.gv.setClickable(false);
            holder.tv = (TextView)cells[position];
        }
        target.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)target.getTag();
    }

    GridView gv = holder.gv;
    gv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    gv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(20, 20));      

    TextView tv = holder.tv;
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, size));     
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);

    return target;
}

class ViewHolder {
    GridView gv;
    TextView tv;
}
}
```

Greets jan
and thanks for any answers

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found a solution myself. I only use the TextView and do the pencilmarks in a 3-line text. This is the easiest way i found.
But i'd like still to know if the switching between Views is possible.